# (Django) Como implementar um botão no template que aciona um método qualquer?

Tags: django, template

Minha dúvida é com relação a implementação de botões em um template qualquer. Eu quero clicar neste botão e o mesmo fazer alguma coisa, como por exemplo exibir uma mensagem na tela. Como eu posso fazer isso? Aqui está uma imagem da minha aplicação que quero acrescentar um botão "exit" que dirá uma mensagem trivial como xau. [image: imagem]

Comment: Você tem duas alternativas, fazer aparecer a mensagem usando `JavaScript` ou colocar link para redirecionar para outro template que tenha essa mensagem, qual é a dúvida?

Comment: Você se refere a implementar um botão usando JavaScript? Desculpe a ignorância é que nunca estudei JS. Minha outra dúvida é se tem como eu criar um botão usando usando HTML em conjunto com as tags de template do Django que acione um método que eu mesmo implementei?

Comment: Como assim? Esse tipo de coisa só pode ser feito via `Ajax`. Se o que você quer é apenas mostrar uma mensagem, ou você redireciona pra outra página ou escreva essa mensagem via `JavaScript`.

Comment: É que meu professor pediu para pesquisar como implementar os meus próprios métodos para serem usados no Django e exir o funcionamento deles em uma tela. Por isso que queria usar o botão para chamar uma ação personalizada.

Comment: Para isso você só tem essas opções que eu mencionei, com `Ajax` você faz uma solicitação ao servidor, processa o pedido e retorna o que você precisa sem atualizar a página. A outra forma é criar uma url que ao acessar trata o que você quer e redireciona para a página de sucesso. Isso aí fica a seu critério.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo o que eu entendi você quer fazer isso em Django. Bom, se no seu caso você quer fazer um cadastro e após o cadastro exibir a mensagem, minha dica seria esta:

E no final da função de cadastro da sua view você dever adicionar um render request, como isto:

```
def nome_da_sua_view(request):
    # Código de cadastro aqui
    return render(request, 'thanks.html', {})
```

Vale lembrar que ela deve ficar dentro da validação se é um método POST, algo como isso:

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
```

Então você deve adicionar nas suas URLS esse redirecionamento:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^thanks/', 'nome_do_seu_app.views.nome_da_sua_view'),
]
```

Por fim, dentro da sua pasta template, deve conter um arquivo HTML chamado thanks.html.

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado pessoal! Fiz muitas gambiarras aqui, foi necessário criar uma url que chama uma view que executa a ação. Implementei a view para ela listar todos os endereços já cadastrados e em seguida colocar a lista num template. Desta forma quando eu clico no botão "exibir cadastros" a tela de endereços cadastrados é exibida imediatamente, isto foi feito com Ajax. 
[image: imagem1]

[image: imagem2]